# How to change 'component/virtuemart' links

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I need to get rid of this 'component/virtuemart'. I've added rewrite rule for that to .htaccess but how can i change links that point to this 'component/virtuemart'?

Comment: You need to adjust the router of that component.

Comment: I don't have any idea about what I actually should edit to change the url

Comment: Well, you can do a pretty ugly hack to the core router (which involves changing `JRouterSite::_buildSefRoute`) in order to remove this URL segment. You can also create a menu item in order to serve as an alias, but I do not know haw well this works for virtuemart, as I do not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Joomla builds routes is based on two parts, the site part and the component-specific part.

In the site part you need to identify the component and usually a view or a task; this is also what you achieve assigning a view to a menu item.

The component-specific part will contain ids and other component specific information.

When a component links to another view / task in the same component, Joomla has to figure out how to render the first part since the menuitem alias of the page that invoked it doesn't match the new request: thus it comes up with /component/virtuemart;  but if you create a menu item that shares the same view and component of the link you want to modify, most likely Joomla will be able to pick it up and render your next links as /thehiddenmenualias.

In order to create a hidden menu item, just create a menu with the hidden links, assign it to a module which you will publish in no position. This is sufficient for Joomla to consider it real, although none of your visitors or search engines will be able to access it.

Comment: And I still just don't get it. Are there any examples?

Comment: You might find some on virtuemarts' forum.  You need to figure out what kind of view you are accessing (i.e "product") and create a menu item that points to that view. After this Joomla should take care of the rest.

Comment: I've got menu item that points to "category" view. It's called "catalog" so I guess links should be like this "/catalog/my_category.html". I can access these pages by these urls but the urls are still old.

Comment: no most likely the menu item you need to create should point to a product page, not a category.

Comment: Now I'm confused even more. I've pointed this menu item to product details and I need to choose one product that will be shown on this 'catalog' page.

Comment: Yes, choose any product. The menu item itself is not important, it just helps Joomla figure out your SEF urls.

Answer (score 0):

In my case urls started to look like "/catalog/category/item.html" after I chose default Virtuemart view as menu item.